# Is there a way to know how many commits a push in a github action contains?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

this is my github action and i would like to know if is there a way to know how many commits are in my push?

Because in my operation i'm trying to run a pipeline of just the files that contains modifications.

```
name: SFDX-CLI DEV Deploy from Repository
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
    paths:
      - 'force-app/**'
jobs:
  SFDX-CLI-DEV-Deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # Fetch all history commit
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: npm install sfdx-cli --location=global
      - run: echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta
      - run: sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${{ secrets.DEV_CLIENTID }} --jwtkeyfile=build/serverDev.key --username ${{ secrets.DEV_USERNAME }} --setdefaultdevhubusername --instanceurl=${{ secrets.DEV_INSTANCE_URL }} --setalias dev
      - run: git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
      - run: sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD^" --output .
      - run: sfdx force:source:deploy -x package/package.xml -u dev
```

I'm not found this information on the net.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me note that you're using `sfdx` above, not `git push`; what `sfdx` does is a mystery black box to me.  I'm answering the question you asked ("how many commits would `git push` push") rather than the one you probably should be asking, but that would probably belong under a different tag [salesforce](/questions/tagged/salesforce), or perhaps on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com.

There is no *completely* reliable way to find out, because any test you perform will have a race condition.  For instance, suppose we have two repositories, **src** and **dst**, and:

```
git push dst refspec
```

is *currently* going to send three commits from **src**, because those are the three commits that do not exist on **dst** at the moment.

We use some process that finds this out:

```
count-commits dst refspec
```

where `count-commits` is our magic command that counts how many commits `git push` will send, and we get the answer: 3.

Now that we have the answer—or just before we get the answer from the counting process—*something else* sneaks in and sends one of the commits *to* the **dst** repository, *or* sneaks in and *removes* one commit *from* the **dst** repository.  We, resting assured that the count is 3, make use of this information in some way.  Then we run the command for real:

```
git push dst refspec
```

and—whoa!—our `git push` sends two or four commits.<sup>1</sup>  What?  How did that happen?

The answer is right there above: someone snuck in *after* we counted, and *changed things*.  We can't stop that from being a possibility.  Race conditions like this usually mean you're doing something wrong.<sup>2</sup>  For instance, in this case, instead of counting in advance, then sending, we should reverse the process: send, and count upon *receiving*.

If this is impossible for various reasons, and/or a "best effort" with possible race condition is *sufficient* albeit imperfect, we can go ahead with the counting.  To do this counting, we:

1. run `git fetch dst` to update any remote-tracking name;
2. use `git rev-list --count remote-tracking-name..local-name`

and the output of this `git rev-list` contains our count.  For instance, if we're going to push to `origin` with `git push origin foo` and the upstream in question is `origin/foo`, a simple `git rev-list origin/foo..foo` gets us the right number (provided we've run `git fetch origin` to get `origin/foo` as close as we can, to keep the race as narrow as possible).  If `origin/foo` is the upstream of `foo`, we can use `foo@{upstream}`:

```
git rev-list --count foo@{upstream}..foo
```

Note that this produces zero if our `git push` is meant to *remove* commits, though in this case we'll need `git push --force` or similar.  To find out (racily) how many commits we'll *remove*, we can use:

```
git rev-list --count foo..foo@{upstream}
```

A forced push operation can both add *and* remove commits all at once; to get both counts, use `git rev-list --count --left-right foo@{upstream}...foo` (note *three* dots here, vs two in the others).  You can reverse the order of the two names around the three dots: with upstream on the left and local on the right, we get the to-be-removed count on the left and the to-be-added count on the right, and if we swap the names, that swaps the counts.

Last, we can close the race completely—at some cost—by using `--force-with-lease` here, given that `foo` has an upstream set.  The push will simply *fail* if we lose a race.  We'll then have to detect the failed push and do something about it, such as trying again (fetch, count, push) in a loop.  This is not very efficient, but if it's rare enough, it might be OK.

---

<sup>1</sup>Four shalt thou not count, neither thou count two, excepting that thou then proceed to three.  [Five is right out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ashgP4YMdJw)

<sup>2</sup>"What do we want?"      **Now!**
"When do we want it?"    **Fewer race conditions!**